# Raspberry Pi and RCA(Analog Camera) Interface

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi

I have an analog camera with AV output and I was looking to interface it with raspberry pi 3.
I am looking forward for some guidance on the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

its very simply provided you follow the steps meticulous. First of all you should have the 3.5mm 4 pole cable connect the pole with yellow white red RCA cables respectively as shown in the image.

[image]

It should be as specified in the picture to work.

Second, once we have connected the RCA cable to TV set,
see to that we follow the exact instructions given here in this link.
[click here](https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/force-raspberry-pi-output-to-composite-video-instead-of-hdmi/03/03/2014)

See to that `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` is commented out. It is needed because you are bypassing the video output to RCA instead of HDMI. See to that the `sdtv_mode=2`, i.e. normal PAL, has been uncommented. Reboot and it is good to go...

Comment: The question was about connecting camera to the pi, not about connecting pi to tv